# Entry point in kafka cluster after sending the message

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a kafka cluster and have build the cluster with kafka from this maven repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10/0.10.0.0

We are using another kafka client library to send messages into this cluster. I would like to log the messages that are sent to this cluster and send them to AWS cloudwatch (my cluster in running on AWS EC2).

How can I achieve this?

Also, once a producer has sent the message, what is the entry point of code that will be invoked in this kafka library?

-Thanks!

Comment: Just write a consumer for these topics? Or you really want to log them on the producer side?

Comment: I don't wan to log them either on consumer or producer, I want to log them on the cluster, when it has received the message and before it is consumed by the consumer.

Only this will ensure that my cluster has got the message.

Comment: I think that you need to rethink the task - either you'll need to modify Kafka source code to log incoming messages - but this is huge amount of work, and you'll need to maintain your fork forever. Or just write consumer and will get data and send to cloudwatch - consumption of messages doesn't remove it from Kafka... I suggest first read more about Kafka itself.

Comment: To add to what *Alex Ott* has said (particularly the part about learning more about Kafka): one of the major reasons for using Kafka is high performance messaging, and the Kafka engine tries very hard to minimize the amount of work that happens to store a message. If you sit in the middle of this and send every message elsewhere -- particularly to a web-service like CloudWatch -- you're going to destroy the performance benefit. It would be better to set up a cronjob on your cluster that regularly rsyncs the Kafka logfiles to another system for offline analysis.

Comment: But, really, if you don't trust Kafka, don't use it.